How do I calculate the error on the extrapolation of a double natural log fit?
I am writing software in Python that tries to fit a data set $t, y$ to the function $y = a \ln(pt) - b \ln(qt)$ and solve for the value of $y$ at $t=30$, denoted $y_0$, and its error $\sigma_{y_0}$.
Fitting the function and getting $y_0$ is easy, but I'm having a very difficult time measuring $\sigma_{y_0}$.
So far, bootstrapping the error has failed to converge, and now I am trying to calculate the error via the partial derivatives of the equation at $t=30$, aka:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial a} & = \ln(30p) \\[6pt]
\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial b} & = \ln(30q) \\[6pt]
\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial p} & = a / p \\[6pt]
\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial q} & = b / q
\end{align}
$$\sigma_{y_0} = \sqrt{\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial a}^2 \mathbf{C}^2_{0,0} + \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial b}^2 \mathbf{C}^2_{1,1} + \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial p}^2 \mathbf{C}^2_{2,2} + \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial q}^2 \mathbf{C}_{3,3}^2}$$
where $\mathbf{C}$ is the covariance matrix returned by lmfit.
The problem is that sometimes, the covariance of the parameters can't be estimated automatically by lmfit (sometimes the signal-to-noise ratio is very low), in which case $\mathbf{C}$ is None.
How can I manually calculate the errors that should be in the diagonal of the covariance matrix, or if that's not feasible, is there another set of terms that I could substitute for $\mathbf{C}$'s diagonal elements?
I've tried the following function:
def covar_double_ln(t, y, result, a, b, p, q):
    J = np.zeros((len(t), len(result.best_values)))
    J[:, 0] = np.log(p * t)
    J[:, 1] = -np.log(q * t)
    J[:, 2] = a / p
    J[:, 3] = -b / q

    # calculate the residuals
    y_fit = double_ln_func(t, **result.best_values)
    residuals = y - y_fit
    
    # calculate the residuam sum of squares
    RSS = np.sum(residuals ** 2)
    
    # calculate the variance of the residuals
    sigma_r2 = RSS / (len(t) - len(result.best_values))
    
    covar = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(J.T, J)) * sigma_r2

    return covar

but this returns singular matrix errors.

As I pointed out in a comment to your earlier version of this question, your model is not identifiable: it is overparameterized.  Until you fix that basic problem, your enterprise is hopeless.  I would be astounded if bootstrapping did converge!

As @whuber pointed out, although I didn't understand what he meant the first few times, the model was overparameterized and that's why it wasn't returning the covariance matrix.
The original equation is:
$$y = a \ln{(pt)} - b \ln{(qt)}$$
Because $\ln(xt)$ can be written as $\ln{x} + \ln{t}$, this can be simplified:
$$y = a \ln{p} + a \ln{t} - b \ln{q} - b \ln{t}$$
$$y = (a - b) \ln{t} + a \ln{p} - b \ln{q}$$
The above equation has two independent components, the coefficient $\alpha = (a - b)$ and the constant $\beta = a \ln{p} - b \ln{q}$.
Thus, the double logarithm model is reduced to:
$$y = \alpha \ln{t} + \beta$$
Fitting this model always returns a covariance matrix, so the error can be calculated from the partial derivatives and the covariance matrix $\mathbf{C}$:
$$\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \alpha} = \ln30$$
$$\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \beta} = 1$$
Thus the error is:
$$\sigma_{y_0} = \sqrt{\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \alpha}^2 \mathbf{C}_{0,0} + \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \beta}^2 \mathbf{C}_{1,1} + 2 \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \alpha} \frac{\partial y_0}{\partial \beta} \mathbf{C}_{0,1}} = \sqrt{\ln(30)^2 \mathbf{C}_{0,0} + \mathbf{C}_{1,1} + 2 \ln{30} \mathbf{C}_{0,1}}$$
